# fusionauth python client ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: fusionauth

when I follow https://github.com/FusionAuth/fusionauth-python-client and try to get fusionauth-client work, it fails to missing python module. Can you point me in right direction?

```
$ sudo pip3 install fusionauth-client
[sudo] heslo pro mlich:
Collecting fusionauth-client
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d6/88/da201734fb5898beb0ec34cc4dd132296f3465da85768ea1979669ef2103/fusionauth-client-1.6.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: fusionauth-client
  Running setup.py install for fusionauth-client ... done
Successfully installed fusionauth-client-1.6.0

$ python3
Python 3.7.0 (default, Sep 20 2018, 07:47:02) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from fusionauth.fusionauth_client import FusionAuthClient
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fusionauth'
```

I use Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was discovered [recently](https://github.com/FusionAuth/fusionauth-python-client/issues/1) and was resolved. Could you try uninstalling and reinstalling the package?

Comment: I had 1.6.0 before and now I have 1.6.2. there is this error now: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. It appears that the requests module was missing from our dependencies. I apologize for that. Python is definitely not our usual environment. I will have this fixed in the next release.

Comment: This problem should be fixed now. Let me know if you have any other problems.